# Why do REST web services not support EJB resource classes outside a war?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, resteasy

In **Jersey**, if we provide the **EJB** resource file (or a **POJO** resource file) outside the war (**in a separate jar**) and package the war and jar inside an ear, Jersey is not able to find them. The same EJB (or POJO) resource files, when placed inside the classes folder of the war are easily discovered. Since packaging the EJBs inside a separate jar and placing the war and jar inside an ear is such a common practice, why does Jersey not provide support for that ? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263176/the-resourceconfig-instance-does-not-contain-any-root-resource-classes-when) is some code for that.

**RESTEasty** also suffers from the same problem when we specify the EJB or POJO resource classes in the Application file (or when we use its auto-scan feature), but provides a **non-standard** way, using **resteasy.jndi.resources** in the web.xml file to list all EJB classes, but there is still no way to provide POJO resource classes outside the war ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a Jersey issue per say, more of a Java EE Classloader design issue...
I'm not sure what you mean by POJO resource, but the way I share POJO classes across subprojects is by creating a separate JAR project which I bundle in my EAR's lib/ directory. That way all my WARs and EJBs can see them.

Comment: Bundling the POJOs inside the EAR's lib is a good practice, but even if we place a simple POJO outside the war inside another jar, we are able to access it from the war without any extra configuration. But in the case of Jersey, if we list a class as a resource class (i.e. a class with @Resource annotation) and place it in another jar outside the war, its not found.

Comment: An EJB JAR is a special type of archive. I think Jersey \@Resources need to be part of a WAR to be managed. If an \@Resource class is put in a EAR's common JAR, I don't think Jersey will scan parent classloaders for annotated classes to instrument and managed.

Comment: But still, the fact that Jersey provides no way to access even EJBs that are present in a jar outside the war, is quite discomforting, given that its such a common packaging scheme. Why should we have to package our EJB classes inside the war ? Before EE6, EJBs were REQUIRED to be outside the war.

Comment: You're right, I would expect an external EJB resource would be accessible. Did you set up the <ejb-ref> in your web.xml?

Comment: That shouldn't be required as I am using the annotations-only approach of EJB 3